# Get name instead of ID one to one relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.8

I have a `make` table and `post` table. `Make` table saves make names as `make_code` and `make_name`.
Post table has a column `make`. While saving a post, it will save make in `make_code`.

While displaying in blade, I want it to display as `make_name`. How can I do it?

Currently `{{$post->make}}` gives me `make_code`. I need it to show `make_name`.

I think its a one-to-one relationship that's needed. I tried putting it in model but did not work. How can I achieve it?

**MAKE MODEL**

```
 class Make extends Model
    {
        public function make()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(App\Post::class);
        }
    }
```

**POST MODEL:**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
}
```

[image: POSTS TABLE SCREENSHOT]

[image: MAKE TABLE SCREENSHOT]

Comment: You have to define the inverse too; so a `hasOne` on your `Post` model. Also, does your `posts` table have a column named `make`?

Comment: yes it does have a column make.

Comment: That's gonna cause problems if you try to define the relationship as `public function make()`. Generally, to relate tables to each other, you define `{table}_id`, so your `posts` table would have a `make_id` column that relates to `id` of `makes`. It's doable the way you have it now, but might be problematic. Either way, define a relationship between `Post` and `Make`. Also, on your `Make` model, the relationship should be `public function post()`, as it relates to the `Post` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

As Tim Lewis noticed:

> the relationships can't be named make, as that's a conflict.

Assuming that the your relationship work like this:

- a `Make` has many `Post`
- a `Post` belongs to a `Make` object.

| Note: Correct me if I'm wrong.

So, if this is correct, you should define your relationships like this:

**Post.php**

```
public function make_rel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Make::class, 'make', 'make_code');
}
```

**Make.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'make', 'make_code');
}
```

> Check the [One-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and [One-to-Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship sections of the documentation.

So, you could do in your controller (or wherever you want):

```
$post = Post::find(1);
dd($post->make_rel->make_name); // 'Harley Davidson'
```

---

Additionally, you could create a computed property as a shorcout to access this related property in your Post model:

**Post.php**

```
// ...

public function getMakeNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->make_rel->make_name;
}
```

Now, you can access it like this:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
dd($post->make_name); // 'Harley Davidson'
```

---

## Suggestion

As a suggestion, I strongly advice you to change your foreign key column from `make` to `make_id` (in your 'posts' table) to avoid conflicts. Also, you could relate the post to the make primmary key instead of a custom key given the fact that this link is almost invisible and it is handled by Laravel. This would speed up the execution of the query because primmary id's are indexed by default.

Comment: Look at the tables; `posts` has a column called `make`, so the relationships can't be named `make`, as that's a conflict. Everything else is correct though, but it's a naming caveat.

Comment: @TimLewis Oh I missed that bit, I'll add it now. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: No problem. I would suggest changing the column name to `make_id` if possible (although the relationship is on code and not id, so maybe not), but having a different relationship name would also work too, something like `public function rMake()` (related make), or similar.